# neo4j table where a list of node keys defines the columns for RETURN

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I choose a specific node LABEL, I can get a list of distinct node KEYS using the below:

```
MATCH(n:Person) 
WITH KEYS(n) AS keys
UNWIND keys AS key
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT key) AS DistinctKeys
```

the result is something like `["Title","Name","Location","Division"]`

I'm looking for a way to loop over this list and return the following equivalent, without having to specify each key:

`RETURN n.Title, n.Name, n.Location, n.Division`

Ideally would accommodate any node LABEL I specify where each LABEL can have varying numbers of KEYS.

Not even sure where to start as looking online it doesn't look possible. Anything I have tried is not even close.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic Cypher statements, the apoc library (https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/running-cypher/) offers the possibilities you need.

Comment: `MATCH (n:Person)
WITH KEYS(n) AS keys
UNWIND keys AS key
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT key) AS distinctKeys
WITH 'n.' + apoc.text.join(distinctKeys, ',n.') AS propertiesString
WITH 'MATCH (n:Person) RETURN ' + propertiesString AS fullQuery
CALL apoc.cypher.run(fullQuery, {}) YIELD value
RETURN value`

Comment: This was the best I could achieve - but this doesn't return a table, but rather a list of dictionaries...